# How can i remove my application from Dock?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, menubar

I created an Application with Swift in AppCode by Jetbrains. The app should be operated only in the menu bar. So i tried to remove it an added the entry Application is agent (UIElement) to YES as Boolean to the info.plist but the icon is not removed from the dock.

Is there anything i miss?